# Is there a sentence that contains every English phoneme?

Tags: phonetics

An example of a sentence with every letter of the alphabet is:
"A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs."

Is there an example of a sentence which contains every English phoneme? I realize accents would skew this. I would be happy to see a sentence in American English accent.